# How can we dynamically hide sidebar for a page in omega theme?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I want to hide second side bar for a page. I am using omega theme.

How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Delta and Context module to configure omega theme for hiding some regions from a particular page or "A types of pages" in drupal.

Here is a very great tutorial -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEeWNi1YCKs